# How to create new column in a data frame using different cells value from other data frame using Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Consider data frames below:

d = {'Purchase Doc':[33772149,33773956,33774567,33775678,33776890],
     'Project':['G-019014PD5','G-019014PD5','G-019014PD5','G-019014PD5','G-019014PD5'], 
     'Order Date':['2017-01-10','2017-04-10','2017-06-10','2018-03-10','2018-051-10'], 
     'GR Date':['2017-01-10','2017-05-10','2017-09-10','2018-04-10','2018-07-10'],
     'Work Package':[1238419,1345678,14567856,1367858,1256987],
     'Material':[70440,70456,70869,70657,70440],
     'GIC':[7331,7334,7326,7326,7331],
     'Value':[20380.80,1345678.70,45678.90,23456.87,65780.85],
     'Currency':['BRL','COP','CLF','PEN','USD'],
     'GR Month':[1,5,9,4,7],
     'GR Year':[2017,2017,2017,2018,2018]}

E2E=pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=[0,1,2,3,4])

f = {'Type':[2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018],
     'Currency':['BRL','CLF','COP','PEN','USD','BRL','CLF','COP','PEN','USD'],   '1':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '2':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '3':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '4':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '5':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '6':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '7':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '8':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '9':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '10':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '11':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234],
     '12':[4.4052,85.5316,1324.95,580.46,1.234,4.6052,85.7316,1356.95,582.46,1.234]}

Data=pd.DataFrame(data=f)

I need to create a new column in E2E, looking for a cell in `Data` where `Data['Type] = E2E['GR Year] and Data['Currency']=E2E['Currency]` and `Data column = E2E ['GR Month']`.

I have already tried many different methods with no success. Can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Please post your example dataframes as text so we can cut and paste them

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)